# Check generic parameter as a specific Prisma type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, prisma

I have an abstract generic class typed as follow:

```
export default abstract class DAO<T, C, S, U, W> {
  [...]
}
```

where `T`, `C`, `S`, `U` e `W` are types contained into `Prisma`. For example, `W` is something like `Prisma._XXXX_WhereInput`.

Into this class there is the following method:

```
protected permissions(): Array<any> {
  
  // Operation based on W type
 
  const userPermission = this.userReferenceByGroup(false);
  const temporaryAssistance = { TemporaryAssistance: { some: { User: { id: this.sub.id } } } };

  return userPermission && [
    this.sub.group === 'pippo' ? temporaryAssistance : {},
    userPermission,
  ].filter(v => Object.keys(v).length !== 0);
}
```

Into this method I should differentiate an object based on the W type. I try using the `instanceof` operator but I have this error:

> Property '_XXXX_WhereInput' does not exist in type 'typeof Prisma'.ts (2339)

How can I do this typechecking in the best way?

## Update

Example of `Prisma` type:

```
export namespace Prisma {
  export type DataloggerWhereInput = {
    AND?: Enumerable<DataloggerWhereInput>
    OR?: Enumerable<DataloggerWhereInput>
    NOT?: Enumerable<DataloggerWhereInput>
    id?: IntFilter | number
    serial?: StringFilter | string
    firmwareVersion?: StringFilter | string
    commercialOrder?: StringNullableFilter | string | null
    internalOrder?: StringNullableFilter | string | null
    ftpURL?: StringNullableFilter | string | null
    ftpUser?: StringNullableFilter | string | null
    ftpPassword?: StringNullableFilter | string | null
    sim?: StringNullableFilter | string | null
    online?: BoolNullableFilter | boolean | null
    creation?: DateTimeNullableFilter | Date | string | null
    bootedSince?: DateTimeNullableFilter | Date | string | null
    idBuilding?: IntNullableFilter | number | null
    idType?: IntFilter | number
    Building?: XOR<BuildingRelationFilter, BuildingWhereInput> | null
    Type?: XOR<TypeRelationFilter, TypeWhereInput>
    Device?: DeviceListRelationFilter
  }
}
```

Here you can find the [playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAOwIYFtgGcxIMbDgBSgEt0Uk4BvAKDlrlEljhgE8w8ARJGJAGwgDmA4FADqACxHAAkgjABXeAF5KNOuqIATAPwAuRPJQAjEWvW10Ionz1x0MYggFnzAMyJQUAdyRRgANRF0IggEW3tHZ3M6bAgUNChsa14AeShNEXCHIic4AB8DXl4XDQQYEWRU9Mz9CJyBfMLi9QBfKjaqBmh4JCMInHhsXiR0dDgOAEEUgB4AFQA+VRcwYgA3bjx2TxJg0IAKAEp9CagoJBZppAQWReoSugB6ACo4WIR7OCR9QhIyADouDx+EIRBIpLIFMoltFaC0ANxwJ4POAPZHTAC0mLg0hgAHIxl5oABrdBUe60PwweRQBBwADa5PMe1EcBy9iuuAgrgIxFISAB3D4gmEYkkfghigOcG0lDguKQuP0uLARDAkFxcBacH0FBaABoUWisQAJKTMMV4EjmvAiKDQRkAXThLg6LSAA) example.

Comment: pls share reproducable example

Comment: @captain-yossarian A reproducable example is a little complicate. I update with an example of `Prisma._XXX_WhereInput` that is contained into the `Prisma` namespace.

Comment: @captain-yossarian I just add the smallest example with the error.

Comment: `W` is a type as well as `Prisma` namespace. You are not allowed to use them as values. Please keep in mind that types are removed during the compilation.

Comment: @captain-yossarian Ok ok now I understand! What is a possible solution to resolve the problem?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Because I need to return a different object based on the `W` type